# GetManifestResourceStream is always returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, console-application, manifest, .net-assembly

I am working in project in which we are using `Groupdocs.total.lic`, and in my main application (ASP.NET MVC), we added nuget packages and executing the below code:

```
var appAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "DocPro.DMS.WebApp.GroupDocs.Total.lic";
using (Stream stream = appAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    ApplyLicenseViewer(stream);

public static void ApplyLicenseViewer(Stream stream)
{
    GroupDocs.Viewer.License lic = new GroupDocs.Viewer.License();
    lic.SetLicense(stream);
}
```

it worked fine, but when I created a new console application and added the below line of code my stream which is returning from `GetManifestResourceStream` is always empty

I added the below code

```
var list = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

in my main application I can see the groupdocs assembly in the list but in my console application the list is empty.

What is wrong here?